# Cant create React Native application using React-Native-cli

Tags: react-native

I followed along the doc of `react-native` and how to create `react-native` application !I set up my `Environment Variables` ! and i installed `python2` and `jdk8` and of course `NodeJs` ! When I type **npx react-native init my app** , I got a blank folder ! I changed the command by adding **--template react-native-template-typescript** in vain ! I also uninstalled `react-native-cli` becauz it may caused some problems unfortunately . I got this error ""**rncli-init-template-kp8iah\node_modules\react-native\template.config.js file** "" . It seems that they are seeking for this file ( rncli-init-template-kp8iah\node_modules\react-native\template.config.js ) I tried several methods to resolve it ( I added in the last of the command `@next` for example . However , nothing changes ) if there any suggestion please help me !! cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Android studio yet? bro?

Answer (score 0):

steps in `react-native` official documentary are proper and work perfectly to complete the installation of react-native.
`react-native-cli` is required to work on a `react-native` environment.

if you still facing the issue please add more details about your development os and target os. also as you mentioned you got a blank folder so check for node version and installed `react-native` version according to your development os.